# How to cut down HTTP request on js/css in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

How to combine css/js in laravel

if I have this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleol.css" type="text/css">
<link href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

how can I make less HTTP request for example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css;css/styleol.css;css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: You need to use a bundling/minification tool like http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/Laravel-JS-CSS-Minifier-Combiner Have you already tried any tools or do you want to know how to use the bundling tool?

Comment: Your best solution is to precompile all CSS together. You can use front-end tools like Grunt to assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use this package, your can call it in your view like this

```
// minify and combine all stylesheet files in given folder
{{ Minify::stylesheetDir('/css/') }}
```

https://github.com/ceesvanegmond/minify

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline#introduction-to-directives), this will automatically combine all of your assets (`css/js`) into a single file and  also `minify` the code into one single file. This means that, the browser will make only one request, and the size of the file could be be greatly reduced.

Read the documentation on `Github` page and install it using `Composer`.

Comment: Authors claim they will not develop this further since L5 includes a method to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel Elixir to combine and minify all your project's CSS file in a single file and you can use the same for your js files.
Read this tutorial http://www.techigniter.in/tutorials/minify-and-combine-css-and-js-using-laravel-elixir/

Comment: This is the official way for L5 but I dislike having to install nodejs just to do this :/